# SwiftUI - Animate text from the start after having displayed it once

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have animated a text displaying a variable inside it when a button is pressed, with the "Spring" animation when displayed.

If the variable changes, the text will only change at the end, where it is displayed.

The problem is that because of this, when the button is pressed again, the "Spring" animation only applies to the end of the text.

I tried so that the button clears the text first and then rewrites it, but the animation still only applies to the part that changes.

Is there any way of making the text reappear again fully, or reanimate it from the start?

Here is the relevant code bit.

```
                Button(action: {

                    self.outputText = "This is my variable: \(variable)."

                }) {
                       Text("Button text")
                   }

                Text(outputText)
                    .animation(.spring())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible approach - just clear & update with a bit delay.

Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
    Button(action: {
        self.outputText = ""
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
            self.outputText = "This is my variable: \(variable)."
        }

    }) {
           Text("Button text")
       }

    Text(outputText)
        .animation(.spring())
```

Comment: This seems to be perfect, thank you very much, I will try this!